# Windsor Castle resolve Dictionary<> failed

Tags: generics, dictionary, castle-windsor

I did the following:

```
    container.Register(Component.For<Dictionary<string, string>>()
                            .Instance(ServiceDictionaryInstance)
                            .Named("serviceDictionary"));
```

The class consumes the component is:

```
 public class BusinessService : IDecisionFilter
 {
     private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _ServiceDictionary;

  public BusinessService(IOtherInterface otherService, Dictionary<string, string> serviceDictionary)
  {
                    _OtherService = otherService,
      _ServiceDictionary = serviceDictionary;
  }
    }
```

Then Castle can't resolve the Dictionary component:

Failed: NotImplementedException
The method or operation is not implemented.
Failed: at Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.GenericDictionaryConverter.PerformConversion(String value, Type targetType)

But if I create another class:

```
public class DictiornayType : Dictionary<string, string>
{ 
}
```

in place of the original Dictionary, everything resolved correctly.

Does this have anything to do with generic type?

Please advise.

Comment: what does the dictionary have? what does BusinessService do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, a dictionary is not really a [component/service](http://castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/concepts/compsservices.html). It's rather a parameter to some component/service. So you can just remove the dictionary registration and pass the dictionary instance as a parameter to the BusinessService component in its registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IDecisionFilter>()
                            .ImplementedBy<BusinessService>()
                            .DependsOn(new {
                                serviceDictionary = ServiceDictionaryInstance
                            }));
```

There is some talk about [removing this difference between parameters and services](https://castle.uservoice.com/forums/38955-windsor-v3/suggestions/455402-get-rid-of-the-arbitrary-division-for-service-para?ref=title) for a future version of Windsor.